# How to apply PolynomialMod to a SparseArray?

Tags: polynomials, sparse-arrays, modular-arithmetic

I have a list `bdrs` of `SparseArray`s, whose entries are polynomials in the variable `t` with integer coefficients. I would like to mod out all coefficients with an integer `m`. A toy example:

```
bdrs={SparseArray[{{1,2}->1+2t+3t^2},{2,4}],SparseArray[{{4,3}->1+5t+7t^3},{4,3}]}
```

When I apply `bdrs=PolynomialMod[bdrs,2]`, the matrices remain unchanged. How can I fix that? 
For comparison, if the matrices contain only integers, then applying `bdrs=Mod[bdrs,2]` works.

First running `SetAttributes[PolynomialMod,Listable];` doesn't help. Also, `bdrs=Thread@PolynomialMod[bdrs,2];` and `bdrs=MapThread[PolynomialMod[#,2]&,bdrs,3];` return errors.

My matrices are very large and sparse (coming from cohomology theories), for example:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that's a bug you should report to Support. Here is a sketch of a workaround: use `ArrayRules[]` to extract your matrix entries, map `PolynomialMod[]` over all these entries, and reconstruct your `SparseArray[]` from this data.

Comment: @J.M. Running `ArrayRules` and `SparseArray` on a large matrix is very inefficient. But still, thank you.

Comment: How "large" are we talking?

Comment: "low density" - if it's not too much trouble, can you post the result of `MatrixPlot[mat]`, where `mat` is your $10^7\times 10^7$ matrix?

Comment: Could try `Map[PolynomialMod[#, 2] &, bdrs, {2}]` though I'd experiment with a smaller example to make sure it does not invoke `Normal` under the hood. Also I doubt the method suggested by @J.M. will be inefficient compared to what would result if `SparseArray` did thread the `PolynomialMod` in the way a `List` would do.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You probably meant `{3}` instead of `{2}`? The former returns `List`s instead of `SparseArray`s, the latter does not alter the input.